# How to tunnel my internet through an iodine client?

Tags: tunnel, iodine

So, I have a vps that has a dns0 networking interface. (I used iodine to use my vps as a client and another vps to use as a server for dns tunnelling). When I open Firefox and browse the internet it shows in Wireshark that those packets inside Firefox were dns. BUT, when I try to use the vps(client) to proxy my internet by using it's port or create a vpn, that packet is shown as a normal tcp/udp packets but not a not dns.

$ip route

```
default via 14.128.14.1 dev ens18 proto static 
10.0.0.0/27 dev dns0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.2 
10.0.0.1 via 14.128.14.1 dev ens18 
10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.1 
14.128.14.0/24 dev ens18 proto kernel scope link src 14.128.14.159
```

$ifconfig

```
dns0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1130
        inet 10.0.0.2  netmask 255.255.255.224  destination 10.0.0.2
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 500  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1  bytes 48 (48.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens18: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet $myIp netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 14.128.14.255
        inet6 fe80::b83a:b1ff:fec2:5f44  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ba:3a:b1:c2:5f:44  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1940754  bytes 183869209 (183.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 926  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 91794  bytes 79877589 (79.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1836  bytes 228911 (228.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1836  bytes 228911 (228.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.8.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 10.8.0.1
        inet6 fe80::5c11:635b:444b:d9c4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 8586  bytes 1515134 (1.5 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 16047  bytes 15462296 (15.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

So, Is there anyway to tunnel my internet through my vps where it shows that the packets I'm sending are dns, not tcp or udp? (I'm using dns over http but this is not working if i tunnel my internet through a specific port)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My apologies, I fixed it and were more detailed about my problem and resolution,